# I am trying to do binary overloading for operator '+' but the output is wrong and I can't understand why?

Tags: c++, binary, overloading

I created a class named `test` having 2 integers. I am trying to overload `operator+` for it. But the output is wrong and I can't understand why.

```cpp
#include <conio.h>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class test
{
    int a, b;
public:
    test()
    {
        a = 0;
        b = 0;
    }

    test(int x, int y)
    {
        a = x;
        b = y;
    }

    test operator+(test t);

    void disp()
    {
        std::cout << "a is =" << a << "\n b is = " << b;
    }
};

test test::operator+(test t)
{
    test temp;
    temp.a = a + t.a;
    temp.b = b + t.b;
}

int main()
{
    test b1, b2, b3;
    b1 = test(10, 20);
    b2 = test(30, 40);
    b3 = b1 + b2;
    b3.disp();
}
```

Comment: Please compile with warnings and errors. The compiler can answer this question.

Comment: Alternatively, please don't ignore the warnings that the compiler is giving you.

Comment: Ok  I tried but I didn't understand

Comment: In the future, add the compiler warnings to the question as well, if you don't understand them. There is usually useful information there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have undefined behavior because your `operator+` is not returning `temp`. You need to do:

```
test test::operator+(test t)
{
    test temp;
    temp.a = a + t.a;
    temp.b = b + t.b;
    return temp;   // <- return here
}
```

Enable all your warnings with something like `-Wall`, and the compiler will tell you about mistakes like this.

Note that the canonical way of implementing `operator+` as a member function is to take the argument by `const&`, and to make the member function `const` as well:

```
test test::operator+(test const &t) const
{
    test temp;
    temp.a = a + t.a;
    temp.b = b + t.b;
    return temp;  
}
```

Comment: @SohailAlam On a side note, your `operator+` should take its `t` parameter by const reference, and should itself be marked as const as well: `test operator+(const test &t) const;` Your `disp()` should also be marked as const, too: `void disp() const`

Comment: @RemyLebeau That's true, added that to the answer as well, thanks.